# SSL failure when using Koala on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ssl, koala

I am trying to set up the Facebook redirection authentication, using Koala with Ruby on Rails, on Windows testing machine.

My current issue that when getting a callback with the "code" parameter, on the line:

```
session['access_token'] = session['oauth'].get_access_token(params[:code])
```

there is the following exception:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in FacebooksController#callback SSL_connect
>   returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate
>   verify failed

which probably happens because my app is trying to use SSL to access Facebook.

I saw several posts describing issues like that, and basically they recommend setting the Koala "http options" parameters `ca_path` or `ca_file`.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to get it work on Windows machine.

I would appreciate helpful instructions on how the exact code that can help me to configure SSL with Koala on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue. I imagine you fixed it by now, but I want to post my solution here for anyone else who needs it in the future:

1. Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and put it in YOUR_APP/lib/
2. Add the following code to your app, for example in an initializer:

   Koala.http_service.http_options = {
     :ssl => { :ca_file => Rails.root.join('lib/cacert.pem').to_s }
   }